# Do the irreducible unitary representations of a locally compact group form a separating set for the Radon measures on the group?

Tags: harmonic-analysis, unitary-representations

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be two Radon measures on a locally compact group $G$. For every irreducible unitary representation $\pi$ of $G$ and vectors $u$ and $v$ from the corresponding Hilbert space $H_\pi$ denote by $\pi_{u,v}$ the respective matrix coefficient, i.e. the function from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$ that maps $g$ to $\langle u,\pi(g)v\rangle$.

Assume that $\int_G\pi_{u,v}(g)\mu(dg)=\int_G\pi_{u,v}(g)\nu(dg)$, i.e. the Fourier transforms of the meausures coincide. Can we conclude that $\mu=\nu$?

My idea to proove this is the following: 
The matrix coefficients of irreducible representations are closed under multiplication (since the tensor product of two irreducible representations is again irreducible) and complex conjugates (consider adjoint operators). Also the trivial representation always exists and by the Gelfand-Raikov theorem, the matrix coefficients separate points. Thus by a (more or less standard) application of the Stone-Weierstraß theorem, we can conclude that the measures coincide on compact sets and hence on all Borel sets (because of inner regularity).

My questions are: 
(i) Is the reasoning I have sketched correct?
(ii) Does this result have a name?
(iii) Where do I find an explicit formulation of this result in the standard literature? E.g. it seems not to be mentioned in Folland's book on abstract harmonic analysis.

I am thankful for any kind of advice.

Comment: It is certainly not true that the tensor product of irreducible $G$-reps is irreducible as a $G$-rep! (This can be seen in the smallest non-abelian group, for instance.)

Comment: Two further questions. (1) When you say "Radon measure" do you assume that the measure is finite?
(2) Do you only want this result for Type I groups, or for more general locally compact groups?

Comment: It surprises me, that you say that the tensor product is not necessary irreducible, if the original representations are. This precise statement is given in Folland's book (Thm. 7.20 on page 217). Furthermore, I do not assume that the Radon measure is finite (even though I am actually only interested in probability measures on Polish groups). Unfortunately I have not heard the term "Type I" before, but I have looked it up and I think the result should hold for arbitrary locally compact groups.

Comment: I do not have a copy of that book, but hopefully it does not literally assert that tensor products of irreducibles are irreducible. As @YemonChoi noted, for non-abelian groups this is rarely the case.

Comment: @paulgarrett Given the general good standard of Folland's book, I assume he means that the tensor product of a G-irrep with an H-irrep is a $(G\times H)$-irrep.

Comment: BTW, @mpw7, you can always edit your own question to include updates.

Comment: I asked about Type I because in that case the left reg rep decomposes as a direct integral of irreps and then I think your result follows for *finite* Radon measures, because coefficients of the left reg rep are dense in $C_0(G)$ and hence separate the finite Radon measures on $G$.

Comment: @YemonChoi, hopefully.

Comment: @paulgarrett I have just checked, and although he does not say so in the statement of the theorem, the remarks just before the theorem indicate that he is talking about the "external" tensor product and not the "internal" one -- this is also clear if one reads the proof of the theorem, as one would expect

Comment: @YemonChoi, ... whew! :) Thx.

Comment: Ok, now I can comment. I think i messed something up with my registration and now the question is not associated with my account. Anyway, thank you for clearing things up so far. But can anyone tell me, if my original statement is still true? Is it true, if I take _all_ unitary  representations, not just irreducible ones?

Comment: If you take all unitary representations then you get in particular the left reg representation, and as I mentioned in another comment the coefficients of the left reg rep are uniformly dense in C_0(G), so should be able to separate Radon measures by regularity

Comment: Sorry that I haven't replied here for a while. @YemonChoi Thank you for your questions and answers, I think that has clarified a lot. I am now quite sure that my original claim is true under the additional assumption that all irreducible representations are finite dimensional (like it is the case for e.g. Abelian groups and compact groups), because that implies that the tensor product of two irreducible representations is always the direct sum of irreducible representations.